# Getting error in function for iterating list of lists

Tags: python, list, function

I am writing a function to pad a list:

```
def pad_data(game_data,nofrounds):
    for i in game_data:
        c=len(i)
        if (c<nofrounds):
            r=nofrounds-len(i)
            value=i[-1]
            for k in range(0,r):
                game_data.append(value)
```

I am getting the following error despite trying numerous times:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Whereas when I attempt to do it this way it gives me result:

```
game_data =[[1,2,3,4,6],[1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,56,0]]               
for i in game_data:
        print(len(i))
5
3
4
5
```

Comment: In your example `i` is a list thus have `len()`; what is the `game_data` you pass to the function?

Comment: I am passing the same game_data I have used in the example to test it.
;Basically I have to use game_data[ i ].append instead of game_data.append which is adding integer to the main list and looping through it due to which it is ending up calculating len of integer added

Comment: oops not game_data.append but i.append

Answer (score 0):

While appending a value, your code is adding an integer in the `game_data` list. `game_data` grows like the following as the function runs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 56, 0]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 56, 0]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 56, 0], 3, 3]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 56, 0], 3, 3, 8]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 56, 0], 3, 3, 8]
```

Notice how initial list is now storing a list of both list and integers instead of just list only.

`len(3)` will then give you the `TypeError`.

Comment: I think I have to use game_data[i].append() instead of game_data.append()